# Multiple foreign keys to the same class

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have those two classes

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="arrow")
public class Arrow {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "id_source")
    private Integer idSource;

    @Column(name = "id_destination")
    private Integer idDestination;

    @Column(name = "capacity")
    private Integer capacity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="id")
    private List<Edge> edges;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="edge")
public class Edge {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private Double latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private Double longitude;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_source", nullable=false)
    private Arrow idSource;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_destination", nullable=false)
    private Arrow idDestination;
}
```

I want idSource to map to id from Edge and also idDestioantion to map to id from Edge...

and I try to link them together but I cannot figure out how... what should be the proper relation between them or should I change the logic of the tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show a relationship between the tables that you want to map to these classes.

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="arrow")
public class Arrow {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "capacity")
    private Integer capacity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="arrow")
    private List<Edge> edges;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="edge")
public class Edge {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private Double latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private Double longitude;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="arrow_id", nullable=false)
    private Arrow arrow;
}
```

P.S. Using @Data for entities smells bad and may cause issues

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="arrow")
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Arrow {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "id_source")
    private Integer idSource;

    @Column(name = "id_destination")
    private Integer idDestination;

    @Column(name = "capacity")
    private Integer capacity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="idDestination")
    private Set<Edge> incomingEdges;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="idDestination")
    private Set<Edge> outgoingEdges;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="edge")
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Edge {
    @EmbeddedId
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private EdgeId id;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private Double latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private Double longitude;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_source", nullable=false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Arrow idSource;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_destination", nullable=false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Arrow idDestination;
}

@Data
@Embeddable
public class EdgeId {

    @Column(name="id_source", nullable=false)
    private Long idSource;

    @Column(name="id_destination", nullable=false)
    private Long idDestination;
}
```